# C++: How to pick out last quarter of elements in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

What is the best way to pick out the last quarter of the elements in a vector containg N elements?

Comment: what's wrong with starting at `(N * 3) / 4`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
size_t   n = src.size();
std::vector<int> dest(src.begin() + (3*n)/4, src.end());
```

`dest` contains the last quarter elements from the source vector `src`.

You can also use `std::copy` from `<algorithm>` header file as,

```
std::vector<int> dest_copy;
std::copy(src.begin() + (3*n)/4, src.end(), std::back_inserter(dest_copy));
```

See the online demo at ideone : http://ideone.com/qrVod

I think, you may want to work more on the expression `(3*n)/4`. Like when `n` is say 5, you want to pick `1` element only, but when `n` is `7`, you may want to pick `2` instead of `1`. So this decision is upto you. My solution just tells you how would you copy the elements, once you decide exactly how many!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, I guess:

```
size_t lastQuarter = myVector.size() * 3 / 4;
for (size_t i = lastQuarter; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
  doSomething(myVector.at(i));
}
```

Comment: Multiply first, or the integer division may not work very well.

Comment: @Tomalak, that explains why they were doing (N * 3)/4 ... it made sense mathematically, but I couldn't see why to do that rather than N*(3/4)...

Comment: @Daniel: Because `(3/4)` is 0. :)

Comment: I understand it now, just escaped me originally :P